# If $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are in Arithmetic Progression, prove that $b+c,c+a,a+b$ are in Harmonic Progression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are in Arithmetic Progression, prove that $b+c,c+a,a+b$ are in Harmonic Progression.

Arithmetic mean: $b^2=\dfrac{a^2+c^2}{2}$

Harmonic mean: $c+a=\dfrac{2(b+c)(a+b)}{(b+c)+(a+b)}$

$\Rightarrow c+a=\dfrac{2ab+2b^2+2ac+2bc}{a+2b+c}$

Plug in $b^2=\dfrac{a^2+c^2}{2}$

$\Rightarrow c+a = \dfrac{2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc}{a+2b+c}$

$\Rightarrow ac+2bc+c^2+a^2+2ab+ac=2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc$

$\Rightarrow 0=0$

I suppose what I did was a proof by contradiction? Where I take it as true that $b+c,c+a,a+b$ are in Harmonic Progression and just went through a calculation to see if it holds? I'm not sure if this is correct and getting a $0=0$ result always makes me feel I made a mistake, but this is all I've got. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of *claiming* that $c+a$ is equal to the Harmonic Mean of $a+b$ and $b+c$, work with just the *expression* of that mean $$\frac{2(b+c)(a+b)}{(b+c)+(a+b)}$$ Expand the numerator (as you did), substitute $b^2=(a^2+c^2)/2$ (as you did), and simplify (*instead of cross-multiplying*, since there's no left-hand side here); you'll find that the numerator factors, and that the denominator cancels, so that the expression *reduces* to $c+a$. Done! (Factoring the numerator might seem daunting, but "knowing" the denominator must cancel, you must be able to pull out a factor of $c+a$.)

Comment: Why can't I claim in the beginning $c+a=\frac{2(b+c)(a+b)}{(b+c)+(a+b)}$? Thanks.

Comment: *"Why can't I claim in the beginning $c+a=\cdots$?"* ... Because that's what you're trying to *prove*.

Comment: Ah :D. But how come the answer below did the cross multiplication from $c+a=\frac{2(b+c)(a+b)}{(b+c)+(a+b)}$? Or is there some subtle difference I am missing here from what I did? Thanks again.

Comment: There is a subtlety involved. Note that the cross-multiplication shows that $(c+a)\cdot\text{denominator}=\text{numerator}$, which says exactly that the numerator factors as expected. It's the same work. So, there *is* a way to structure the argument around multiplying, and a way around multiplying. However, it seemed to me more conceptually straightforward to prove "the harmonic mean of [this] and [that] is [thut]" by calculating the harmonic mean of [this] and [that], and then directly reducing the result to [thut].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:\begin{align}1=2&\implies0\times1=0\times2\\&\implies0=0.\end{align}Would you deduce from this that $1=2$? I somehow doubt it…

However, your approach is easy to repair. As you wrote, you want to prove that$$c+a=\frac{2(b+c)(a+b)}{(b+c)+(a+b)}=\frac{2ab+2b^2+2ac+2bc}{a+2b+c}.\label{a}\tag1$$And you are assuming that$$b^2=\frac{a^2+c^2}2.$$So, \eqref{a} is *equivalent* to$$c+a=\frac{2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc}{a+2b+c}$$and\begin{align}c+a=\frac{2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc}{a+2b+c}&\color{red}\iff(a+c)(a+2b+c)=\\&\phantom{\iff}\qquad=2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc\\&\color{red}\iff a^2+2ab+2ac+2bc+c^2=\\&\phantom{\iff}\qquad=2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc.\end{align}Since this final equality clearly holds, \eqref{a} holds, and therefore the statement that you wish to prove is true.

Comment: Can you please tell me which part of what I wrote is saying 1=2? Because this means I have a wrong concept (which is worse than a miscalculation). Thank you.

Comment: At no point whatsoever I said that you wrote that $1=2$. I simply explained, through an example, that there is no way of deducing that an assertion $P$ is true from the fact that $P\implies0=0$.

Comment: Ah I see. So the point is not to cancel everything out in the end and get $0=0$ which would destroy the proof, but to show both sides are equal: $ac+2bc+c^2+a^2+2ab+ac=2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc$. I think I understand better now thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with getting $0=0$. Actually, the assertion $a^2+2ab+2ac+2bc+c^2=2ab+a^2+c^2+2ac+2bc$ is equivalent to $0=0$. But there is no need to get to that point.

Comment: How come this is valid: $c+a=\dfrac{2ab+2b^2+2ac+2bc}{a+2b+c}$ if it is what I'm trying to *prove*? I suppose I mean I have no way to say the equality holds. Yet cross-multiplication was how I showed both sides are equivalent.

Comment: You *don't* know whether it is valid or not. But it is still true that that assertion is equivalent to $(c+a)(a+2b+c)=2ab+2b^2+2ac+2bc$.

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> If $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are in Arithmetic Progression, prove that $b+c,c+a,a+b$ are in Harmonic Progression.

First, an implicit assumption is that $\,(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)\ne 0.\,$

Notice that $\,a,b,c\,$ are in A.P. is equivalent to $\,a-2b+c=0.\,$

Thus $a^2,b^2,c^2\,$ are in A.P. iff $a^2-2b^2+c^2=0.\,$

Notice that $\,a,b,c\,$ are in H.P. iff $\,1/a,1/b,1/c\,$ are
in A.P. by definition.

Define the quantities
$$ q_1 := a^2-2b^2+c^2,\quad
q_2 := \frac1{b+c} - 2\frac1{c+a} + \frac1{a+b},\\
q_3 := (a+b)(a+c) - 2(a+b)(b+c) + (a+c)(b+c). $$
Verify that
$\,(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)q_2 = q_3 = q_1\,$ when expanded.

By the implicit assumption, $\,q_1=0\,$ iff $\,q_2=0.\,$

Now $\,q_1=0\,$ iff $\,a^2,b^2,c^2$ are in A.P. and
$\,q_2=0\,$ iff $\,b+c,c+a,a+b\,$ are in H.P.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Where did $q_3$ come from? Thanks.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson Did you read "$\,q_1 = (a+b)(a+c)(b+c)q_2 = q_3\,$ when expanded."?

Comment: Yes I can see the equation stands, but how did you know that? I would never in a million years be able to see $q_1 = (a+b)(a+c)(b+c)q_2$.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson Do you understand "$q_2=0\,$ iff $\,b+c,c+a,a+b\,$ are in H.P."? $q_3$ is the numerator of $q_2$ over the common denominator. Now expand $q_3$ with cancellation to get $q_1$.